# I am trying to detect movement on screen but get an error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, opencv

Modules I am using: `PIL`, `cv2`, & `numpy` and `time`
I made this small code that will capture movement on screen and if someone or something moves it will put an cascade on the object that `cv2` thinks moved.

My code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time


def Screen():
    while 1:
        Screen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(13, 32,805, 623)))
        cv2.imshow(" ",cv2.cvtColor(Screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(Screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        last_time = time.time()

        print("Fps: " + str(last_time))

        for (x,y,w,h) in gray:
            cv2.rectangle(Screen,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

        pass

        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff

        if k == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Screen()
```

Error I get:

```
for (x,y,w,h) in gray:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: What are you expecting `gray` to contain?

Comment: cvtColor returns an `image` object, not a tuple.  Check `gray` by printing it's type information.

Comment: gray is a 2d array containing the value of each pixel in gray scale

Comment: What are you expecting `for` to iterate over?

Comment: Grayscale images typically only have **one** component, the intensity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, assuming you mean by `w,h (width, height)` , you can get `w,h` without the need to loop over the image using:

```py
w,h = gray.shape
```

Second thing is that `gray` is actually a 2d numpy array containg the value of each pixel at the corresponding position in the array

if you want to loop over the image for each `x,y, val`, you can achieve that like this:

```
for y, row in enumerate(image):
  for x, pixel_val in enumerate(row):
     # do whatever you want you have w,h,x,y, pixel_val
```

If you don't need `pixel_val`, then just simply loop over the limit without involving the image with you

```py
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
         # do processing here you have w,h,x,y
```